# why trigger console twice when i use koajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I try koajs today and write the helloworld example:

```
/**
* index.js
*/
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(function*(){
  this.body = 'hello world';
  console.log('success!');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

then I run the index.js file and visit the localhost:8080 in browser, but the console.log seems triggered twice everytime I refresh the page. why ?

Answer (score 5):

Look at your network tab in your browser console or log the requests on the server, it's a request for the favicon.

You can log your server request like this

```
app.use(function*(){
  this.body = 'hello world';
  console.log(this.url);
});
```

You will see in your console :

```
/
/favicon.ico
```

Comment: you are right, you can't view the favicon request in the developper console. But two solution : in chrome you can watch all events throught chrome://net-internals/#events ( and then filter with your URL ) or , best is to log server requests